# How to display a view on the same page when I click on a link/button in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I want to display a view on the same page in an Angular application when the link is clicked.
The page should not open in a new page, instead it should be displayed in the same page, beside the list component.
How to achieve this?
Illustration of what I want:

[image]

I am trying to achieve this using angular routing but not able to do so.

Comment: You'll need to take a deeper look at the angular router :  https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route and the router-outlet.

Comment: You might want to give it a try and than ask a new question about the specific part you would have difficult with. SO provides us with a good guide as to [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with a better chance to get the help you are after.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a router outlet.
I advise you to follow the entire Tour of Heroes tutorial in order to learn the fundamentals of Angular, in particular to your question you should have a look to Part 5: navigation
https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt5

in Tour of Heros you have "Dashboard" and "Heroes" buttons. This is what you try to achieve with your links as a list.